# comparing properties within Typescript objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
searchFilteredData = [ { productId: 12345, carrierId: 3, //otherstuff } 
                       { productId: 28664, carrierId: 5, //otherstuff } ]


proposalProducts = [ 0: 12345, 1: 28664 ]
```

I have 2 arrays, one has a property `productId` that can match items in the second array. How can I perform a loop to determine which items in `searchFilteredData` have corresponding records in `proposalProducts`?

Comment: The second array is not valid JS or TS

Answer (score 2):

Just use `filter` with `includes` to check if element is in array:

```
searchFilteredData.filter(({ productId }) => proposalProducts.includes(productId))
```

```js
searchFilteredData = [ { productId: 12345, carrierId: 3 },
                       { productId: 28664, carrierId: 5 },
                       { productId: 28232, carrierId: 5 }]


proposalProducts = [ 12345, 28664 ]


inProposalProducts = searchFilteredData.filter(({ productId }) => proposalProducts.includes(productId))

console.log(inProposalProducts)
```

Answer (score 0):

The common method is to create a new array with matching elements using `Array.prototype.filter`

```
let items = (searchFilteredData.filter(ele => proposalProducts.includes(ele.productId) )
```

---

If you want to loop through manually, use `Array.prototype.forEach` or `for-of` loop directly.

```
for (let item of searchFilteredData){
   if (proposalProducts.includes(item))
      console.log(item);   //do something
}
```